# Is there a way to truncate this massive IF/AND statement?

Tags: excel

I have a massive IF statement that does multipliers by an array of 5 `(1, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.3)` and I assign the numbers it's multiplying based off values in two columns. The 3 numbers that will be multiplied by that multiplier array are `42,000` `46,000` `52,000`

Is there any way to shorten this?

`=IF(AND(E2="R1",F2=1),42000,IF(AND(E2="R1",F2=2),42000*1.1,IF(AND(E2="R1",F2=3),42000*1.15,IF(AND(E2="R1",F2=4),42000*1.2,IF(AND(E2="R1",F2=5),42000*1.3,IF(AND(E2="R2",F2=1),46000,IF(AND(E2="R2",F2=2),46000*1.1,IF(AND(E2="R2",F2=3),46000*1.15,IF(AND(E2="R2",F2=4),46000*1.2,IF(AND(E2="R2",F2=5),46000*1.3,IF(AND(E2="R3",F2=1),52000,IF(AND(E2="R3",F2=2),52000*1.1,IF(AND(E2="R3",F2=3),52000*1.15,IF(AND(E2="R3",F2=4),52000*1.2,IF(AND(E2="R3",F2=5),52000*1.3)))))))))))))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
=INDEX({42000,46000,52000},MATCH(E2,"R"&{1,2,3},0))*CHOOSE(F2,1,1.1,1.15,1.2,1.3)
```

Alternately, you can make it more modular by putting in a couple of lookup tables.  This way it will be much easier to modify in the future if you need to add any additional conditions.  The lookup tables can be stored anywhere, I just used these columns as examples:

[image]

Now your formula becomes (adjust the vlookup columns as necessary for wherever you put the lookup tables):

`=VLOOKUP(E2,$K:$L,2,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(F2,$N:$O,2,FALSE)`

If preferred you could also wrap it in an IFERROR.

Comment: Solution verified! Thank you!